# openLDAP Structural objectClass not found

Tags: openldap

I am new to openLDAP setup.
I have openLDAP server and i connected it from apache directory studio client.
when i tried to search "domain" and "inetOrgPerson" objectclass it is not found in list.

i tried to search issue in google and found that need to include schema file from /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema in slapd.conf but it is showing me following error :

/usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema: line 78 attributetype: Duplicate attributeType: "2.5.4.2"

is there any solution of it?

Comment: 1. Define 'not found in list'. 2. Do you *have* objects of that class in the DIT? If so, the schema is already loaded and the problem lies elsewhere. If not, searching for them won't find anything: why is this a surprise?

Comment: 'not found in list means' when i clicked on new entry then object classes dialog box appeared and in that  i searched it but it was not found.can i need to include schema in slapd.conf to make them available?

Comment: `inetOrgPerson` is defined in, err. `inetOrgPerson.schema`, not `core.schema`, and `core.schema` would already have been loaded, so you're loading it twice, so you're getting 'duplicate' errors.

Comment: Thanks...it helped me to solve problem.